# Why is Kubuntu Restarting?

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I'm a new user to Kubuntu: I usually use Window 7 or MacOS.

My question: when I close the lid on my laptop it should go to sleep or hibernate, and when I open it it should wake up and start where it left off. Instead it restarts and all the apps I had open have been closed. Why is this happening?, Its never been a problem with Windows 7 on this computer.

Answer (score 1):

How big is your swap? System may crash when hybernate because swap size is smaller than RAM size, so kubuntu can't copy it there.